# Trouble with dynamixel_controller

Tags: ros, dynamixel, dynamixel-controller, ax12

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Greetings, I am attempting to use the dynamixel_controller stack to control an ax-12 servo. When I attempt to launch the node I get an error stating "Could not open port /dev/ttyUSB0 [Errno 2] no such file or directory: '/dev/ttyUSB0.' Now I've checked to make sure my usb2dynamixel is connected to ttyUSB0 with minicom and it is. After looking at my log I think it may have something to do with use_sim_time? My log file can be seen below, any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
[rospy.client][INFO] 2011-12-13 17:53:19,667: init_node, name[/dynamixel_manager], pid[2400]
[xmlrpc][INFO] 2011-12-13 17:53:19,668: XML-RPC server binding to 0.0.0.0
[xmlrpc][INFO] 2011-12-13 17:53:19,669: Started XML-RPC server [http://ubuntu:59821/]
[rospy.init][INFO] 2011-12-13 17:53:19,669: ROS Slave URI: [http://ubuntu:59821/]
[rospy.impl.masterslave][INFO] 2011-12-13 17:53:19,669: _ready: http://ubuntu:59821/
[xmlrpc][INFO] 2011-12-13 17:53:19,671: xml rpc node: starting XML-RPC server
[rospy.registration][INFO] 2011-12-13 17:53:19,672: Registering with master node http://localhost:11311
[rospy.init][INFO] 2011-12-13 17:53:19,770: registered with master
[rospy.rosout][INFO] 2011-12-13 17:53:19,849: initializing /rosout core topic
[rospy.rosout][INFO] 2011-12-13 17:53:19,855: connected to core topic /rosout
[rospy.simtime][INFO] 2011-12-13 17:53:19,858: /use_sim_time is not set, will not subscribe to simulated time [/clock] topic
[rospy.core][INFO] 2011-12-13 17:53:19,877: signal_shutdown [atexit]
[rospy.impl.masterslave][INFO] 2011-12-13 17:53:19,883: atexit
[rospy.client][INFO] 2011-12-13 17:53:47,887: init_node, name[/dynamixel_manager], pid[2510]
[xmlrpc][INFO] 2011-12-13 17:53:47,888: XML-RPC server binding to 0.0.0.0
[xmlrpc][INFO] 2011-12-13 17:53:47,889: Started XML-RPC server [http://ubuntu:50528/]
[rospy.init][INFO] 2011-12-13 17:53:47,890: ROS Slave URI: [http://ubuntu:50528/]
[rospy.impl.masterslave][INFO] 2011-12-13 17:53:47,890: _ready: http://ubuntu:50528/
[xmlrpc][INFO] 2011-12-13 17:53:47,891: xml rpc node: starting XML-RPC server
[rospy.registration][INFO] 2011-12-13 17:53:47,892: Registering with master node http://localhost:11311
[rospy.init][INFO] 2011-12-13 17:53:47,990: registered with master
[rospy.rosout][INFO] 2011-12-13 17:53:48,069: initializing /rosout core topic
[rospy.rosout][INFO] 2011-12-13 17:53:48,075: connected to core topic /rosout
[rospy.simtime][INFO] 2011-12-13 17:53:48,078: /use_sim_time is not set, will not subscribe to simulated time [/clock] topic
[rospy.core][INFO] 2011-12-13 17:53:48,097: signal_shutdown [atexit]
[rospy.impl.masterslave][INFO] 2011-12-13 17:53:48,104: atexit
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12335/trouble-with-dynamixel_controller/) by [StephenS](https://answers.ros.org/users/1532/stephens/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-12-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It has nothing to do with use_sim_time parameter, it being set or not will not influence how dynamixel driver will operate.

It looks like it can't find the ttyUSB0 file, can you add an output of:

```
ls -la /dev/ttyUSB*
```

to your question, just to make sure that it is indeed there?

Could you also add configuration and launch file that you used to start everything up?

---

Originally posted by [arebgun](https://answers.ros.org/users/18/arebgun/) with karma: 2121 on 2011-12-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0